# Amazon Transfer Utility in Android Hogging bandwidth

Tags: android, amazon-s3, upload, android-volley, bandwidth

I am using new Transfer Utility for Image upload to S3 buckets.

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(3AccessKey, s3SecretKey);
ClientConfiguration config  = new ClientConfiguration();
config.setMaxErrorRetry(0);
config.setSocketTimeout(60000);
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, config);
uploadTransferManger = new TransferUtility(s3Client, getApplicationContext());
```

By using this , I am uploading 1 image at a time. This happens in background.
At this time, if I do any HTTP request in Android, via browser or programmatically via Android Volley, these requests get timed out.

Can anyone provide a solution for this.